# OrientDB: is it possible to add/set fields to an existing class on the fly?

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB beginner here!

I am setting up a graph to simulate a social network. I have started by creating a new class, Person, and I have several persons on file I want to enter.

But my problem is that all fields are not present all the time. My first Person I want to enter have FirstName and FamilyName. The second entry have those two but also Age.

But when i run

```
select from Person
```

my result pane only show FirstName and FamilyName of my two records. My assumption was that I would see all three columns, FirstName, FamilyName and Age with Age being empty for the first entry.

So I assume that adding a new "field" or property on the fly is not accepted.

What would then be the best practice to achieve add the extra property on the fly, given that I don't know all the possible fields before I start (no schema)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first execute following statements:

```
create class Person extends V
create vertex Person set FirstName = "Jon", FamilyName = "Doe"
create vertex Person set FirstName = "Johanna", FamilyName = "Doe", Age = 30
```

and after that execute select, output will be something like this:

```
orientdb {db=DoctorDB}> select * from Person


+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|FirstName|FamilyName|Age |
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+
|0   |#91:0|Person|Jon      |Doe       |    |
|1   |#92:0|Person|Johanna  |Doe       |30  |
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+
```

and then:

```
update #92:0 set Sex = "Female"
```

now select outputs:

```
orientdb {db=DoctorDB}> select * from Person

+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|FirstName|FamilyName|Age |Sex   |
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+------+
|0   |#91:0|Person|Jon      |Doe       |    |      |
|1   |#92:0|Person|Johanna  |Doe       |30  |Female|
+----+-----+------+---------+----------+----+------+
```